# VL53L0X Assembly Soldering Problem

Tags: soldering, assembly, distance, solder-paste, solder-mask

We have a product(PCB) in mass production as using VL53L0X.

There is a problem with some of our products.

We tested before sending customer. There is no problem. But, over time we have received complaints from customers. In this case, We can't communicate with VL53L0X.

I want inspection report from the soldering company.

Can anyone explain and comment on the report? What is the meaning of gray circle that mentioned with red marked? Why are some small and some big? Could the problem I'm having be because of soldering?

I attached full report as a google drive link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TuGtgAzskEg01juk0zyNGUpHgvrcmMKi/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is air inside of the solder-bumps. If you would make a vertical cut, then there would be inside of the solder nothing and at the sides walls made from tin.
Possibly the squeegee method is not good or the temperature is to low.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with very similar QFN parts. QFN and BGA is a pain to work with quality-wise.

The report shows an X-ray of a batch of PCBs, as is custom for inspection of QFN and BGA components where you can't see the actual solder joints.

Since properly made solder joints are metallic consisting mostly of tin, a proper solder joint will show up as dark since metal blocks x-rays more efficiently than other materials (and probably the X-ray is tuned to display the joints as black). The gray areas would be those where there's only copper from the pad/trace and no solder. (You can even see the bond wires of the IC.)

So the grey dots indicate that the solder has not "wetted" entirely across the pad. A few minor bubbles of air like that wouldn't be an issue, but larger areas might cause problem over time when the PCB is exposed to oxidation.

I think the person who made the report was checking to ensure that there is a solid "square" around each such bubble, in which case you might be able to reason that oxidation won't cause problems over time. I still think they were quite lax approving all of these, because there is clearly a quality problem here. Maybe they smell a warranty claim.

As reference for how to do this "by the book", I checked what the formal IPC-A-610 soldering standard says.  I couldn't find anything about QFN specifically, but for SMD with flat pads, then generally the criteria is that at least 50% of the pad must be covered unless there is an explicit "voiding criteria" - how much of the pad you allow to leave uncovered. This is more or less tolerant depending on if you specify a certain IPC class. Serious assembly companies ought to follow class 3 (highest) unless otherwise specified. Some of the pads on the picture are covered a lot less than that... possibly ok for IPC class 1, not ok otherwise. These boards will not pass IPC class 3 inspection.

As for what could cause this:

- Poor flux/paste.
- Too low temperature.
- Poor PCB layout/thermal relief in case of GND pins (the layout looks ok in this specific case).
- Oxidated PCBs and/or IC. Poor vacuum packing of PCBs and/or IC.
- Too little paste.

Comment: Thanks your detailed comments @Lundin and Today, I forwarded your feedbacks to soldering company.And I received soldering profile from the company.  I have attached as link related profile image. 

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TDwBJrBhq-drGrHB8PIMyqO-fzTGwmsS/view?usp=sharing)

I wanted increasing of soldering temperature as +%20 from company. So, Company will solder again and send again inspection report. I will share results with you.

Comment: @FAFİ It sounds like what you actually need is more of authoritative statement from a consultant specializing in soldering. I've taken IPC classes for hand soldering certification but I wouldn't claim to be an expert on reflow soldering. Companies who perform IPC certification are usually also available as consultants, maybe one of these can help you: https://www.ipc.org/certification-centers