X-Ray inspection criteria
We are seeing board problems when testing a new batch of boards at high temperatures (70°C).  This is using leaded solder (and OEM leaded BGA balls) and the component is rated to 100°C.
We believe one possible root cause could be solder fractures or other solder process issues.  Here are 2 X-Ray photos.  I notice there are definitely voids, and they appear close to the PCB pads (so probably in the solder paste?).  It is supposed to be IPC Class 3 compliant and the CCA manufacture says it is ok.  I also don't have an Xray of any previous (working boards) to compare it with.


Can anyone suggest how to best determine if there is a solder issue?

I'm not hugely familiar with x-ray inspection and am somewhat new to using BGAs at all, but to an uninitiated layperson like myself, the amount of voiding here seems excessive. What flux are you using?

We can find out but this assembly is being done by a board assembly house (not in-house to our company).  While I would normally defer to their judgment since they do this every day, I would feel better if there were another informed opinion.

Related post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/665331/6102. When I looked it up back then the criteria was that 50% of the pad should be covered. But please note that I'm not by any means an expert of BGA/QFN soldering (the guys doing this every day hopefully are). It can become problematic if there are spots near the edge of the balls where oxidation might enter though. Also those who are actual BGA experts (I'm not) might have something to say about gas expansion across temperature ranges.

As me move through the investigation, there definitely appears to be an issue with the solder.  We removed and desoldered one unit and the problem went away and the manufacturer tweaked there reflow profile and for a sample of 2 it appears to have fixed the issue.

I see you changed the profile and solved the problem, but in the future here's an experiment you might try if you suspect it's a paste problem. Cut out a small piece of an old stencil and hand print various sections of a solder sample board with different paste lots / vendors. Place glass slides over the patterns and send the board through the oven and inspect the "joints" afterwards.
